# Limit number of checkboxes in Android Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've been trying to figure out how to limit the number of checkable boxes in my preferences activity.

I'm using the preferences activity to make a number of select-able options but only want to let 5 be selected at a time. So once the fifth one is selected the others grey out. But when one is deselected the rest un-grey.

The only problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to set an OnClickListener to any of the preferences checkboxes or something similar.

Anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think I figured it out. What I was looking for is:

```
final CheckBoxPreference myBox = CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("CheckBoxItem");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is suppose to do the work assuming that you want to put listener on one checkbox.

```
final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
checkbox_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

     //do whatever you wish to do when that checkbox is checked

   }
}
);
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to reference elements in a preferences xml as opposed to a layout xml.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand. Could you please clarify a little more?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. What I was looking for is: 'final CheckBoxPreference myBox = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("CheckBoxItem");'